# Trying to simplify $ \sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}\frac{1}{k^l}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}. $

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

I am trying to simplify the following expression:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}\frac{1}{k^l}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.
$$

I am wondering if I can simplify the sum away where $l\in\{1,2\}$. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean when $l=1$ or $l=2$?

Comment: I want to simplify the expression in both cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Both Maple and [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+Binomial%5Bn%2Ck%5D%2Fk*p%5Ek*%281-p%29%5E%28n-k%29+for+k+from+1+to+n) express the sums using generalized hypergeometric functions: for $l=1$,
$$ np \left( 1-p \right) ^{-1+n}\;
{\mbox{$_3$F$_2$}(1,1,1-n;\,2,2;\,{\frac {p}{-1+p}})}
$$
and for $l=2$,
$$np \left( 1-p \right) ^{-1+n}\;
{\mbox{$_4$F$_3$}(1,1,1,1-n;\,2,2,2;\,{\frac {p}{-1+p}})}
$$
It's possible there might be a simpler form, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

EDIT: If your expression is $S_l(n)$, the generating function of $S_1$ seems to be

$$ g_1(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty S_1(n) x^n
 = \frac{\ln(1-(1-p)x) - \ln(1-x)}{1-(1-p)x} $$

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure if it helps, but the expression I initially provided is part of another expression which I hope to simplify as a whole. Here is the form:

$$
\sum_{n}\sum_{k=1}^n{j\choose n}{i-j\choose m-n}{n\choose k}\frac{n^{l+1}}{k^l}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}
$$

Answer (score 1):

For $l=1$: take the lower bound $\frac{1}{k} > \frac{1}{k+1}$, multiply by $\frac{p(n+1)}{p(n+1)}$
$$
S_{n+1} \geq \frac{1}{p(n+1)}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{k+1} p^{k+1}(1-p)^{n-k} = \frac{1}{p(n+1)}\bigg(1-(1-p)^{n+1}\bigg)
$$

Comment: am not sure I understand. So you don't set  to ? I tried setting  to  and I ended up with the expression$$\int_0^p\left[\frac{(1-p+y)^n}{y}-\frac{(1-p)^n}{y}\right]dy$$

Comment: @kreyszig aplogies, this approach doesn't work because $x=x(p)$, and after substituting $x=\frac{p}{1-p}$ there's still $(1-p)^n$ left outside the integral, so $x$ can't be used as a variable. But here's a good lower bound.